# Regex: match and replace on a date

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to convert the date separators in a date.

So, from 11.11.2009 -> 11-11-2009

Could someone help me do that with a regex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
my_date = my_date.replace(/\./g, '-');
```

Comment: Sweet, I'll note this for the future.

Answer (score 3):

You mean `'11.11.2009'.replace(/\./g, '-')`.